# Java Timeline of Events

Tags: java, events, time

I am making an `Animation  Studio` with  JAVA. I want a timeline of events to know which event happens when, a bit like `Windows Movie Maker`:

Anyone know of any `JAVA` program which can do so?

I don't want to go through *all* the work of drawing a box for the event, adding a `MouseListener`...

Answers are **greatly** appreciated!!!

Comment: So you want a ui control which would do this for you? Why the `optimization` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home. This animation library will help you a lot.